# xorg configuration 10bpc/30bpp

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, display

I'm trying to set my display into 10bpc (30bpp) depth.
I should mention my video card and display are capable of this since it's working from MS Windows.

After adding the following lines to a file under my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d directory:

```
Section "Screen"
       Identifier "Screen0"
       DefaultDepth 30
       SubSection "Display"
               Depth 30
       EndSubSection
EndSection
```

there were some changes in my xorg.0.log ... but insufficient to make the change (presumably due to the `8 bit DAC` line) (I included the warning, maybe it helps)

```
[   356.589] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   356.616] (II) AMDGPU(0): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[   356.616] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   356.616] (**) AMDGPU(0): Depth 30, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   356.616] (II) AMDGPU(0): Pixel depth = 30 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[   356.616] (==) AMDGPU(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   356.616] (==) AMDGPU(0): RGB weight 101010
[   356.616] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using 10 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[   356.616] (--) AMDGPU(0): Chipset: "AMD Radeon VII" (ChipID = 0x66af)
```

without the config file those lines from the xorg log look like:

```
[   482.778] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   482.808] (II) AMDGPU(0): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[   482.809] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   482.809] (II) AMDGPU(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   482.809] (==) AMDGPU(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   482.809] (II) AMDGPU(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[   482.809] (==) AMDGPU(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   482.809] (==) AMDGPU(0): RGB weight 888
[   482.809] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[   482.809] (--) AMDGPU(0): Chipset: "AMD Radeon VII" (ChipID = 0x66af)
```

So the thing I included in the config seems to be useful but not sufficient to switch to 30bpp/10bpc.

My question is what else needs to be set up or what is the misconfiguration that results in me still having just an 8 bit image sent to my display although mesa is using 10 bits per channel?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your configuration is actually correct, but the 8-bit DAC is actually a limitation of your card or monitor.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter):

> [I]t is not unusual for a television or video projector to truthfully claim a linear contrast ratio (difference between darkest and brightest output levels) of 1000:1 or greater, equivalent to 10 bits of audio precision even though it may only accept signals with 8-bit precision and use an LCD panel that only represents 6 or 7 bits per channel.

You're actually using 30-bit color to the video card and getting an equivalent difference in contrast ratio, but the card or monitor isn't really capable of displaying all of those 2^30 colors, and Xorg is just telling you like it is.

Comment: That's not actually the case, since, as mentioned in the first sentence of my question both my video card and my display are capable of it since it works from Windows. Also the display shows a logo on switching ... and there are different picture settings on it if it's in 10bpc mode.